# How to find the points where the slope of the tangent is $-1$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

For the function $f(x) = x^3 - 4x$, find the   points where the slope of the tangent is $-1$. Use the algebraic method.

Do I need just to find zeros?

Comment: let the tangent be $y=-x+c$. Now substitute $-x+c$ in place of $f(x)$ to get the point of intersection of the given function and the tangent. You will get an equation with two variables and you cannot solve it.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative is

$$f'(x)=3x^2-4$$

The $x$-coordinates of the points where the slope is $-1$ can be found by solving

$$3x^2-4=-1 \Leftrightarrow x^2=1$$

Comment: Its actually $3x^2-4=-1$

Comment: Is there any other way to find points without using derivatives because this course is advance functions not calculus. The derivatives were not introduces yet.

Comment: @DaryaChenskikh no.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that the slope of the tangent is the geometric interpretation of the derivative.

So you want to find when the derivative of $f(x)$ is $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

The slope of the given equation at any point is given by $\frac {d}{dx}f(x)=3x^2-4$

Since the tangent is $-1$ so $3x^2-4=-1$ and then you get $x=+1,-1$.